# Questions regarding importing csv into neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have three questions regarding importing csv:

1. Is it possible to make the command to ignore the first line in the csv files? (As there are many files to import, it is inconvenient to change all of them)
2. Is it possible to make the property of a relationship or node to be null if the corresponding property in csv files is empty?
3. Is it possible to have the same type of nodes with different (number of) properties?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes you can use SKIP as well in LOAD CSV :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dummyfile.csv" AS row
WITH row
SKIP 1
MERGE (n:Node {id: row[0]})
```

2) If the csv column value is NULL, then the corresponding property value will be null as well. If it is empty, then the property will not be created

Assume the following CSV :

```
id,title,desc
1,title 1,desc1
2,,desc 2
```

And the following LOAD CSV :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ikwattro/ed85bfc98c9298924c154ecf3e0ab2aa/raw/54a9303c365a7698c87728d458f8de703a9c22e1/load.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Post {id: row['id'], title: row['title'], description: row['desc']})
```

This would create the following :

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                               │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"description":"desc1","id":"1","title":"title 1"}│
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"description":"desc 2","id":"2"}                 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

3) Yes, Neo4j being schemaless you don't need to have the same number of properties on nodes with the same label

Comment: Thank you. About 2), the column value is not NULL, the column is just empty. Would the corresponding property value also be null?

Comment: So if the column is empty, then the property value will not be set. Editing my answer

Comment: For 1): Am I correct that "WITH row" is essential, while "Merge..." is not?